# Highlight multiple rows with specific ID's

Tags: jquery, html, highlight

Looking for solution to highlight `<td>` elements in table, with specific ID's on hover.

My code

```js
    $('#orderstable').hover(function()
    {
        $('#id_1').find('td').addClass('hover');
    }, function()
    {
        $('#id_1').find('td').removeClass('hover');
    });
```

```css
#orderstable td
{ 
    padding:0.7em;
    border:#969696 1px solid;
}

.hover
{
    background:yellow;
}
```

```html
<table id="orderstable">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Proces</th>
        <th>Step 1</th>
        <th>Step 2</th>
        <th>Step 3</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>Proces 1</td>
        <td id='order_2'>job 2</td>
        <td id='order_1'>job 1</td>
        <td id='order_3'>job 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Proces 2</td>
        <td id='order_3'>job 3</td>
        <td id='order_4'>job 4</td>
        <td id='order_1'>job 1</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

What I'm trying to achieve is when you hover mouse over td cell with id='order 1', it will highlight this `<TD>` and also other td's with id='order_1'.
Of course, I need same functionality for other id's (order_2, order_3 etc).

Any idea?

Comment: Id's must be unique .... use classnames instead

Comment: Is there any singularity between the items with same id ?? maybe to avoid the use of useless classnames

Comment: Please, check my updated fiddle, I had a mistake on the previous one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IDs have to be unique. You should be using classes. Ie. `class="order1"` and `$('.order1').addClass(...)`. Also, your JS is way off, as you're selecting items that don't exist, and targeting the `td`s *inside* those selectors, instead on the tds themselves. To achieve your goal, I would do something like this:

```
$('#orderstable').on('mouseover', 'td', function() {
    var elemClass = this.className
        .split(' ') // Gets array of classes
        .filter(function(item) {
            return item.match(/order_\d/) || false;
        }) // Filter down to classes matching 'order_[NUMBER]'
        .pop(); // Get the class. (Actually gets the last item in an array that contains only one item, so same thing.)
    $('.' + elemClass).addClass('hover');
}).mouseout(function() {
    $(this).find('td').removeClass('hover');
});
```

[Here's a JSFiddle demonstrating this.](https://jsfiddle.net/TheQueue841/w15sp93k/)

Realistically, you can also do something like the following for every individual class:

```
$('.order_1').hover(function() {
    $('.order_1').toggleClass('hover');
});
```

But I decided to "automate" this.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using classes instead, however to answer your question you can achieve this by using the nth child css pseudo.

I created a quick JSFiddle here as an example. 
https://jsfiddle.net/fzjuxyeL/8/ - Updated working!

```
#order_1:nth-child(1n+1)
// Start at 1 and increment by 1 finding all divs with ID

$('#order_1:nth-child(1n+1)').hover(function(){
    $('#order_1:nth-child(1n+1)').toggleClass('toggled')
});
// Applies class to all divs with specified ID when hovered
```

Comment: This only works if you hover over the first item of a respective ID.

Comment: Hi, great, just replaced ids with classes and this is exacly I'm looking for!

Comment: @QuangdaoNguyen Sorry I hadn't noticed that, however I found a fix and have updated it hopefully this helps